# Is twelve moon upper demon moon 1 in a whole completely different level than the rest of the upper demon moons?

Tags: demon-slayer

Currently in the manga twelve moon upper demon moon 1 is ,

> Fighting 3 demon slayers hashiras at the same time, including the most powerful hashira , plus another demon slayer (4 demon slayers total)

and before,

> Zenitsu (not officialy a hashira yet, though likely in hashira level) fought upper moon 6 and defeated him alone

Is twelve moon upper demon moon 1 in a whole completely different level than the rest of the upper demon moons, or is there any other upper moon which comes close to his level?

Comment: being able to master 2 breadth styles as a demon is completely broken and op..

Comment: @gameon67 2 Breath Style? Kokushibou?

Answer (score 1):

Upper Moon 1 Kokushibo is definitely strong in his Moon Breath Techniques but can't seems to use any Blood Demon Techniques. I have to say, Upper Moon 2 Doma is quite near his level since his summons can already deal with Hashira level Demon Slayers. Doma's weakness is his glutonny and his overconfidence since he always lets his enemy injure him.

Answer (score 1):

In addition, Akaza has gained a power boost which i think could be on par with Kokushibo since his the only one who can regenerate his head even after decapitation. Sad to say we weren't able to witness it since he decided to giveup on his own.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Anime & Manga Stack Exchange and enjoy your stay. There is no need to add another answer if you just want to add something that goes hand in hand with your previous answer: you can directly edit your first answer and add that bit to it ;)

Comment: I also recommend to use spoiler tag since everything you've said is not yet showed in the anime.